# Trouble understanding registers x86

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, irvine32

I've been trying to teach myself how to accomplish certain tasks in assembly.

Right now, I am working on trying to detect palindromes. I know I could use a stack, or possibly compare strings using Irvine's library, but I'm trying to do it via registers.

The problem is, when it comes to using registers, I'm more than a bit confused.

The following compiles, but when I get to the CMP line, the program breaks and gives me this message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x004033FC in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x0000000F.

I'm assuming it has something to do with how I set the registers, but even using the registers while debugging isn't helping me much.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

enteredWord BYTE "Please enter the string to check: ", 0
presetWord BYTE "Step on no pets", 0

isAPalindrome BYTE "The word is a palindrome. ", 0
isNotAPalindrome BYTE "The word is not a palindrome. ", 0

.code
main proc
mov ecx, SIZEOF presetWord - 1
mov esi,OFFSET presetWord

checkWord:
MOV eax,[esi]
CMP [ecx],eax
JNE NOTPALIN

inc esi
dec ecx
loop checkWord
mov edx, offset isAPalindrome
call WriteString
jmp _exit
main endp

NOTPALIN PROC
mov edx, offset isNotAPalindrome
call WriteString
ret
NOTPALIN endp


_exit:
exit


end main
```

Comment: You used `ecx` as a pointer but instead loaded it with a length. Also, you operate on 4 bytes at a time instead of 1. Use `mov al, [esi]; cmp [presetWord+ecx], al` instead.

Comment: You set `ECX` to be *number of characters*, then you use it as a pointer to memory. It will not point to anything reasonable so of course it will crash. You need to set `ECX` to offset + length, not just length.

Comment: @Jester So using that, I would still have to do `mov ecx, OFFSET presetWord + SIZEOF presetWord - 1` ?

Comment: Since you use `LOOP` to iterate, you need to keep using `ecx` as counter, so no. If you switch to pointers, you need to change that too. Of course it's enough to check half the string so that might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you. It's stable now. Now I just have to figure out why it's automatically deciding the compared values aren't equal. I'm testing it out on the word _banab_

Comment: And I did notice this one after answering: `dec ecx` `loop checkWord` -> this will create infinite cycle for odd values in `ecx`, as the `loop` itself will decrement `ecx` (going from 0 to -1 instead of ending). For even values it will work.

Answer (score 1):

CPU register is piece of computer memory located directly inside the CPU core. Piece of computer memory means some amount of bits (0/1), in case of 64b x86 CPU the general registers are 64 bits "wide", under names `rax, rcx, rdx, rbx, ..`.

The `ecx` is the lower 32b part of `rcx` (upper 32b part is not accessible under special name, only through instructions using `rcx`). And the lower 16b part is accessible through `cx`, which is composed from two 8b parts `ch` (upper), and `cl` (lower).

So as you are using `ecx`, you can set 32 bits to either 0 or 1. Which can interpreted as unsigned number from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (in hexa `0 .. 0xFFFFFFFF`), or as signed number from -2<sup>31</sup> to +2<sup>31</sup>-1 (`0x80000000 .. 0x7FFFFFFF`). Or you can interpret the meaning of those bits in any way you wish, and write code for.

In your code you can utilize three common ways how to interpret value of bits in some CPU register.

```
; EBX as memory address:
mov   ebx,OFFSET presetWord  ; some address into memory (32b unsigned number)
; ECX as numeric value ("unsigned long" in C++)
mov   ecx,SIZEOF presetWord - 1  ; 15
; AL as ASCII character (extended 8 bit)
mov   al,[ebx]      ; also shows how memory is referenced by address
; AL == 83 == 'S' => value of memory at address "presetWord"
```

In your example doing `cmp [ecx],eax` means to reference memory at address 15, which is fortunately for you illegal, so it does crash. If you would by accident use some legal address for your process (but not the one you wanted to really use), it would silently proceed and continue with unexpected result.

You probably did want to do `cmp [esi+ecx],eax`, which means to reference memory at address `presetWord+15` (last char of string), but that's true only for first iteration. Then you do `inc esi` and it will point at `presetWord+1` address (second char).

And you probably wanted to compare only characters, so you should change that `eax` to `al` to fetch/compare only single byte at one time, because the string is encoded in ASCII encoding (8bit per char). `eax` would work for UTF-32 encoding.

---

To check for palindrome you may want to load one register ("r1") with address of first char, one register ("r2") of address (!) of last char, and then do this loop:

- if (r2 <= r1) -> exit with true (all important chars compared) (check addresses as unsigned numbers)
- here addresses r1 < r2 -> now compare characters
- if (byte [r1] != byte [r2]) exit false
- ++r1, --r2  -> adjust the addresses to point at second/second last chars
- loop to beginning

This will produce "false" for presetWord, as `'S' != 's'`, so you may want to introduce case insensitivity to the `if (byte [r1]...` part, but I would first make it work without that.

---

While debugging, you should be able to recognize "class" of some of those numbers in registers. If you load size into register, it will be very likely some small number, like `0000000F` (15). Address will be very likely some large number like `8040506E`. ASCII characters when used as single char should lead to something like `20` - `7F` in common cases, but if you do `mov al,...`, the debugger is still displaying whole `eax`, so the upper three bytes will remain it's previous value, for example reading space character into `eax` set as `12345678` will change the value of `eax` to `12345620` (space `' ' == 0x20` in ASCII).

You can also use memory view to check content of particular address in memory. If you would for example change that `cmp` to `cmp [esi+ecx],eax`, and check that address in memory view, you would see it would point in second iteration again at the last char, not the second last char.

This is all visible and possible to check in the debugger, sometimes a bit tedious, then again often easier than asking on SO or just thinking about the source code, especially if you are stuck for longer time.

---

Finally ... why even registers? Because computer memory is separate chip. And it may look innocent, but instruction like `mov al,[presetWord]` may actually stall for hundreds of CPU cycles, while the CPU chip will wait for the memory chip to read the content of memory and send it over bus wires to the CPU chip. While the `al` and `ecx` is directly inside the CPU, accessible in the same cycle when the CPU needs it.

So you may want to store values into register, if you use them often in your calculation, to not slow down with memory (although once the memory content is cached by L0/1/2/3 caches, the "hundreds" of cycles becomes reasonable amount, sometimes even 0 cycles with cache level directly on CPU chip). But you want to access memory in predictable pattern (so cache can read-ahead), and in reasonable amounts (caches work usually with sizes like 16-32B up to 4-8k by their level). If you access in couple of instructions like 16 different 8k memory pages, you may run out of available cache-lines, and then there will be at least one access featuring full stall, waiting for real memory read.

Comment: As a side note.. in Assembly there are no "types" of variables, or anything. It's your code, which gives those bits a meaning/structure. So you have to be always aware of the size of data you work with, like that ASCII char is 8 bits. So you write code reading only single byte and adjust pointer by +-1. If your data would work over 16b, you will want to read word, and adjust pointers by +-2, or use *2 in addressing, like `mov ax,[esi+ecx*2]`. So make sure you understand what those 8/16/32 bits means, and what is byte/word/dword, and check how common types are encoded in C++ (as inspiration).

Comment: As I wrote in a prior comment, I am testing the string "banab", yet it still fails. Also, here is what my code looks like,since it was updated: http://imgur.com/a/pUJYa

Comment: Also, with regards to size, can't I just do `mov ax,[esi+ecx*TYPE presetWord ]` ?

Comment: @BHope what is `TYPE presetWord`? In address calculation you can't use anything, only fixed scale factors are supported by x86 (it's not math expression, it's picking one of hard-wired modes). So you can do *1, *2, *4 and in 64b I think *8 works too. For one index register. But that's address calculation. It doesn't matter, if the `ax` is fetched from `[esi+ecx*1]` or `[esi+ecx*4]`, that's different address. But you still fetch 16b of data, because `ax` is target register. If you are fetching from ASCII string, then `ax` will contain 2 characters. (`ah` will be 2nd from +1 address, `al` first)

Comment: @BHope: about code from screenshot. You are still decrementing `ecx` twice, and `banab` has odd length, so you are creating infinite loop, which is broken only by failing char test reporting "not a palindrome". Use debugger and watch `ecx` and read what `loop` does. BTW, don't use `loop`, it's artificially slowed down on modern x86 to not break ~1980-90 code which was slowing down execution by doing empty loops. Rather write full `dec ecx` `jnz loop`. In your case it should also fix the problem.